# sequence in an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ such that $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $$\lim_{p \rightarrow 1 ^ {-}} (1-p) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n p^n = x.$$

I think I am getting a little confused when there are double limits, so that might be part of my problem. Do I first take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ or $p \rightarrow 1^{-}$?

Comment: First as $n\to\infty$.  (Well technically as the upper-bound of the summation, which is different from $n$, approaches infinity.)

Comment: The expression to evaluate is in term of $p\rightarrow1^-$, so this is what you need to evaluate. You would need the limit "$x_n\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$" along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following difference: $$x - (p-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n p^n = (p-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x p^n - (p-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n p^n = (p-1) \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x-x_n)p^n$$

For a given $\epsilon$, can we find a $p$ close enough to $1$ that this expression is within $\epsilon$ of $0$?  We will need to first choose a large enough $N$, then...