# What is the radius of convergence of the power series $ f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^{n} $ Prove that $\lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)f(x) = L $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was wondering if someone could tell me if my work for this problem is correct?

Let $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n= 1,2,...$ and suppose  $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L > 0 $.

What is the radius of convergence of the power series

$ f(x)=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^{n} ? $

Prove that $\lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)f(x) = L $

My solution is below:

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L $ then given $e=L/2$ there exists

$M \in N$ such that $ L/2 \leq a_n \leq 3L/2 $

if $m > M$ so $ \sqrt[n]{L/2} \leq \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq \sqrt[n]{3L/2} $

Thus $ 1= \lim \sqrt[n]{L/2} \leq \lim \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq \lim \sqrt[n]{3L/2} = 1$

hence the radius of convergence is 1.

Note that $ (1-x)f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^{n+1}  $

$ = a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}( a_n -a_{n-1}) x^n $

so $ \lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)f(x) = a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (a_n -a_{n-1} )  $

since $ a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{k} (a_n -a_{n-1})  = a_k $

we have that $a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (a_n -a_{n-1})  = \lim a_k = L $

Comment: This looks excellent! Full marks!

Comment: You need to justify the step $\lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)f(x) = a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (a_n -a_{n-1} )$, where you interchange limit and infinite summation.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/930405/42969.